# What's the right way to detect double-click events with python pyglet?

Tags: python, events, mouseevent, mouse, pyglet

I've looked at [pyglet mouse events](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/mouse_events.html),
which nicely deal with common events like clicking, dragging, and releasing the mouse buttons. I want to handle double-click events, but this doesn't seem to be as straightforward.

Should I just monitor for mouse_press and mouse_release events, and compare time intervals and locations to detect double-click events?

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. **Is there a 'best practice' for detecting double-click events with pyglet?**

This approach is the best I've got so far:

```
import time
import pyglet

class MyDisplay:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = pyglet.window.Window(100, 100)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_release(x, y, button, modifiers):
            self.last_mouse_release = (x, y, button, time.clock())

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
            if hasattr(self, 'last_mouse_release'):
                if (x, y, button) == self.last_mouse_release[:-1]:
                    """Same place, same button"""
                    if time.clock() - self.last_mouse_release[-1] < 0.2:
                        print "Double-click"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, it seems pyglet measures the time between clicks using [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html).

To describe what I am talking about, here is a small excerpt from pyglet's source code:

```
t = time.time()
if t - self._click_time < 0.25:
    self._click_count += 1
else:
    self._click_count = 1
    self._click_time = time.time()
```

(The full version of the function can be found [here](https://www.assembla.com/code/pywiic/subversion/nodes/trunk/lib/pyglet/text/caret.py?html_id=85&load_comments=true&rev=31#ln527). Please note that in the full version the code is geared towards selecting text.)

The source code also hints at using a GUI toolkit so that it can monitor click events.